# How to remove operator symbols, like + - / *, from a list

Tags: clojure

How do I check if a list contains operators? I'm trying to filter out the operators from a list.

For instance `(func '(= a (* b c)))` should return `(a b c)`

I've tried `symbol?` but that leaves the operators in the list

Comment: Please also add the code you have tried - even it does not work.  It might off just a little bit and might be used as base for an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a simple hash-set and the `remove` function

```
(def operators '#{ + - * / =})

(defn remove-operators [coll]
  (remove operators (flatten coll)))

(remove-operators '(= a (* b c)))  =>  (a b c)
```

You need to quote the set `operators` so Clojure does not evaluate the *symbol* `+` and replace it with the *function* `clojure.core/+`. We also use `flatten` to turn the original abstract syntax tree of the expression into a simple sequence, before discarding the symbols we don't want.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're trying to do is remove *specific* symbols (+ - / *) from a list, and any lists in that list, recursively.

```
(remove #{'+ '- '* '/} '(= a (* b c)))
```

This uses the set `#{'+ '- '* '/ '=}` as a predicate function with `remove`. If any element in the list is in that set, it gets `remove`d.

But to match your example output, we must add `'=` to the set of symbols, and the list(s) must also be flattened:

```
(remove #{'+ '- '* '/ '=} (flatten '(= a (* b c))))
=> (a b c)
```

If you wanted to preserve the nested lists, you could do something similar with `clojure.walk`:

```
(clojure.walk/postwalk
  (fn [v]
   (if (list? v)
     (remove #{'+ '- '* '/ '=} v)
     v))
  '(= a (* b c)))
=> (a (b c))
```